# Insufficient Access to the record

Tags: visual-workflow, access

I am creating a task and custom record using a flow and for temperory use creating another custom object record, after the transaction is done the flow will delete the 2nd custom record, here I am running into the following errror.
The flow tried to delete these records: null. This error occurred: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY

but Actually the User is having all permissions except modify all.
this flow is invoked from the Account where as the 2nd temperory record doesnt have any relation ship like lookup or master but have a text field which stores the account Id.

When I execute the same delete using apex with invocable it is executing well.
When I give modify all, with no apex invocable also working.
I want to understand actually why the delete not working unless I give modify all or invocablemethod.this 2nd custom object not have any realtion ship.

Comment: My gut reaction is that Flow might put a read only lock on records created within the flow itself, or at least prevent a delete command within the same flow.  Although I'm not sure if a Flow constitutes multiple transactions or if it's all considered one transaction

Comment: Account is public read only the user who is initating the flow is the owner of the account, does this make any impact even though there is no direct relationship except holding the account Id in text field.

Comment: Is the running user a) the owner of the Custom Object being deleted, b) has CRUD (delete) privileges on that custom object, and c) no trigger or other process is changing the owner of the custom object to someone other than the running user

Comment: He is the Owner, after giving the modify all permission on the temporary 2nd custom object , issue resolved. Due to some reasons these accounts hold old temporary en custom object records and they not owned by the current user so the flow is throwing the error. As the FLOW RUN IN USER MODE this issue is happening.